# What's the meaning of "Client is disabled" error message?

Tags: linkedin-api

My website implements login with linkedin. I open a popup with the following URL and receive the linkedin login page with an error at the header saying "Client is disabled". I couldn't find any documentation for this error, so any help would be appreciated.

Accessed URL: "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=..."

Comment: Most likely: the client_id corresponds to a client and this client has a status and this status is disabled.

Comment: thx. any idea how to enable it again?

Comment: I assume there should be some "application" administration page @linkedin

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error when trying out OAuth2 flow as described in [1].

The reason was the clientId value I used belonged to an app created in my linkedin developer account some time back and was deleted later. When I registered a new app and used the new clientId, the issue was resolved.

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/04/retrieving-user-profile-information.html