# Linkedin clients not showing

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Linkedin OAuth pop up throwing error  saying "Client is disabled". When i checked for the app in linkedin dev console there is no app. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332445/whats-the-meaning-of-client-is-disabled-error-message